# New line is ignored while submitting text

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

On client side i am using jquery and server side spring MVC.

I have a text:

```
This is line1


This is line2
```

If i submit it in DB it is stored `This is line1 This is line2` means new line `\n` is ignored.

Why?

Comment: You're typing it within a textarea?

Comment: Yes sometimes inside textarea and sometimes inside a div

Comment: How do you know it is stored on a single line? Do you display it back on an HTML page?

Comment: yes when i am displaying it in html all new line is ignored

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace the `\n` chars by `<br />` to see the line breaks on an HTML page. For example in Java:

```
String outputWithBr = inputWithoutBr.replaceAll("[\\r\\n]+", "<br />");
```

Comment: r u saying that when it is displayed back in html all `\n` is converted to `<br>`

Comment: Your text contains `\n`. If you display it as is, no line break will be displayed, since HTML line breaks are `<br />` (the line breaks will still be displayed in the source code though). You thus need to replace any `\n` by `<br />` before giving it to your view.

Comment: on server side its working now. but on client side its still problem.i am using `$.text()` to read the text of div. when i display text in textarea using `$.val()` its ignoring newline.again back when setting div content from text area its ignoring new line